# Issues installing mod_wsgi - cannot find Makefile.in

Tags: mod-wsgi

I'm trying to rebuild mod_wsgi and am running into this issue? Does anyone know what's going on here?

```
/tmp/mod_wsgi-3.4# ls
config.log     LICENCE           posix-ap2X.mk.in   win32-ap22py31.mk
config.status  Makefile.in       README
configure      mod_wsgi.c        win32-ap22py26.mk
configure.ac   posix-ap1X.mk.in  win32-ap22py27.mk
root@vps-547073:/tmp/mod_wsgi-3.4# ./configure
checking for apxs2... no
checking for apxs... no
checking Apache version... ./configure: line 1704: apxs: command not found
./configure: line 1704: apxs: command not found
./configure: line 1705: apxs: command not found
./configure: line 1708: /: Is a directory

checking for python... /usr/bin/python
./configure: line 1877: apxs: command not found
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: error: cannot find input file: Makefile.in
```

Answer (score 40):

See the mod_wsgi instructions:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickInstallationGuide#Apache_Requirements

It says:

> On Linux systems, if Apache has been installed from a package
>   repository, you must have installed the corresponding Apache "dev"
>   package as well.
>
> For most Linux distributions, the "dev" package for Apache 2.X is
>   "apache2-dev" where the corresponding Apache package was "apache2".
>   Some systems however distinguish the "dev" package based on which MPM
>   is used by Apache. As such, it may also be called "apache2-worker-dev"
>   or "apache2-prefork-dev". If using Apache 2.X, do not mix things up
>   and install "apache-dev" by mistake, which is the "dev" package for
>   Apache 1.3 called just "apache".

You are missing that dev package for Apache. This is why 'apxs' cannot be found and subsequent issues occur.

Comment: A stupid question, I know, but where would I find the appropriate name for the package on a different distro? Specifically, on the amazon web services brand of linux?

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem trying to `pip install mod_wsgi` in `virtualenv` in `Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon`.

Comment: Your answer was correct and helped me and no offence, but your profile picture freaks me out :D

Answer (score 33):

Try to install apache-dev. Use below command in terminal to install.

```
sudo yum install httpd-devel
```

OR

Ubuntu/Debian: `sudo apt-get install apache2-dev`

Comment: Ubuntu/Debian: `sudo apt-get install apache2-dev`

Comment: Thanx @PierredeLESPINAY